# Lithium Polymer Battery Touching a Stepper Motor

Tags: batteries, motor, temperature, stepper-motor, lithium-polymer

I posted this question in the Arduino forums, but I thought I would post it here too for a broader audience of advice.

> Hey there everybody :) I’m Cal and am super new to Arduino. I’ve been into programming for a long time, but only software stuff - I’d never hooked it up to some hardware. But, a friend of mine needed a fake CCTV camera to be hooked up to a stepper motor, so that it can be controlled with an RC transmitter. I’ve always wanted to learn about this stuff, so I said I’d give it a go!

> I’ve gotten quite far - everything seems to be working, the last step is hooking up the motor to the camera. The reason I’m posting on here is to ask a question (and please let me know if I’ve posted this on the wrong board).

> I have an 11.1V Lithium polymer battery (SiGP) and a NEMA 17 stepper motor. I only discovered, after some testing, how hot the stepper motor gets when it runs. Fortunately, it’s not hot enough to melt the plastic on the camera. Today I decided to put the components into the camera and get an idea of how it would all fit. It all looks good, but my problem is - there is no way to fit everything in without the stepper motor touching the battery.

> As I say, I’m very new to this, and batteries freak me out. I definitely don’t want an explosion or fire hazard in this project. The camera will be used for around 45 minutes at a time, with long gaps in between uses.

> So, long story short, is it safe to have a LiPo battery touching a stepper motor? It’s a very confined space and I will definitely need to drill some ventilation holes, but I thought I’d come to you guys for some advice.

> Thank you in advance! Any advice is greatly appreciated :)

A user on the arduino forum asked me about the required voltage and current of the motor. The website I bought it from it says:

> "12V rated voltage at 350mA max current (driving it at lower voltages is fine, but you'll have less torque)"

Thanks to anybody who can give me some advice and/or alternatives if the motor and the battery touching would be unsafe.

Comment: I try to keep my lipos under 50 deg C - I recommend you measure the temperature of your stepper after a full and complete use cycle. It does sound like there’s very little load on the stepper so perhaps you can adjust the drive current to limit heating as well